# How do I modify Entity Framework 6 using Npgsql 3 to use an SSL connected string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, ssl

So far what I've tried is to verify that my certificates for SSL are correct and through command line (Using psql) and through a console application (Npgsql) I'm able to reach the database with SSL enabled (No password needed). This is working.. My problem starts with the SSL.

The application I'm working on has working Data Access to Postgre using Entity Framework 6 on non-SSL. However when I try to update the string to use SSL, I need to find a place to pass in the client-certificates. I've looked at different places. Right now, I have changed the `DbContext()` constructor to use `base(DbConnection,bool)` so that I can pass in a connection that has been provided the callback method. However, I get this error:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I've tried to apply different fixes from SO to solve this error, but to no avail.

Anything helps!